# Jenkins Git integration issue

Tags: java, git, github, jenkins, github-for-windows

Installed Jenkins, Git plugin (window platform), then I will create a new item (maven project) in Jenkins.

While configure the git I’m getting the error

Project- Configure – Source code management – git
Enter the repository url : `https://github.com/zzzz/Sample.git`

Getting below error

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/zzzz/Sample.git HEAD
```

Jenkins – Manage Jenkins –configure system

git

Path to Git executable = `git.exe`
In this section getting the below error

```
    There's no such executable git.exe in PATH: C:/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath, C:/Windows/system32, C:/Windows, C:/Windows/System32/Wbem, C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/, C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/,
 C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/, C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/, C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/, C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/, C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/, C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/,  C:/Program Files/Java/bin, %M2_HOME%/bin, C:/Program Files/glassfish-4.0/bin.
```

Please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Manage Jenkins** > **Global Tools Configuration**.

Reconfigure your git executable path. Find the path where git is installed on your local machine and add this path upto the git.exe file in the required input field..

Comment: Little bit confusion,  my project files in my IDE (netbeans) configure with remote repository (github), do you want to install git in my local machine? and if Jenkins configure in server, then how can i get the source?

Comment: Install Git on the machine  where Jenkins is hosted.

Comment: thanks installed Git, and gave the complete path for the git.exe. now it's working

Answer (score 3):

For me it looks like, you don't have the Path, where git is installed in your Windows Path, so jenkins doesnt find `git.exe`.
To resolve, you should look for your git installation and add the folder with `git.exe` inside to System path.